# Applying theme changing mechanism at run-time with css var

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, styles

I'd like to use css var() in order to change themes on my website at run-time. Every time a user selects a theme, I *import* the correspondent file into the page. But once I import an **already** imported css file, the style on the page doesn't get updated. I tried to solved it by removing the former css theme file from the  tag, but it doesn't appear there as a  tag with an *href* attribute, but rather as a  tag with no possible way to query it and remove it.

For example:

Main.css:

```
.header {
   background: var(--primary-color);
}
```

ThemeA.css

```
:root {
--primary-color: red;
}
```

ThemeB.css

```
:root {
--primary-color: blue;
}
```

Is there any way that I can solve it, or do I have to seek for an alternative solution? and if so, which solution is most suitable?

**Edit**

I do the *import* inside a react component. Here's an essence of how I do it:

```
export const MyComponent = ({theme) => {
   import(`../styles/${theme}.css`);
   /* rest of the code */
})
```

Comment: Can you please show us how you add the newly imported theme.

Comment: This is a hunch... try doing `import('../styles/${theme}.css?t='+Math.random());` - if it works I'll add an answer :)

Comment: @JoelPeltonen but my css file name is ${theme}.css and not ${theme}.css?t=0.5401442778824308 (for example). If I add the Math.random() as a suffix, I get a file with a different name and the css module can't be found

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I tried it with a <link href='...> tag instead, it didn't give an error but it also didn't work :/

Comment: @OP Yes, but that's kind of the point The `?t=something` adds a random query parameter each request, which bypasses certain caches. In practically all servers I have ever used that serve static files can ignore extra query parameters, unless the parameters are used for generating the file. So then you have a different GET request, causing the browser to treat it as a new resource.

Comment: If your backend doesn't deliver the correct CSS file while ignoring the query param; I am curious; what is your backend?